DPDK can't allocate memory for Network Card
I am a beginner in using DPDK. I followed the guide below:
https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/index.html
When I was running the sample hello world program, I received the following outputs:
Arguments : ./dpdk-helloworld -l 0-3 -n 4
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 32
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: No free 1048576 kB hugepages reported on node 0
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Using IOMMU type 1 (Type 1)
EAL: pci_map_resource(): cannot map resource(32, 0x2180800000, 0x800000, 0x0): Cannot allocate memory ((nil))
EAL: Failed to map pci BAR0
EAL: 0000:07:00.0 mapping BAR0 failed: Cannot allocate memory
EAL: Requested device 0000:07:00.0 cannot be used
EAL: Using IOMMU type 1 (Type 1)
EAL: pci_map_resource(): cannot map resource(32, 0x2181000000, 0x800000, 0x0): Cannot allocate memory ((nil))
EAL: Failed to map pci BAR0
EAL: 0000:07:00.1 mapping BAR0 failed: Cannot allocate memory
EAL: Requested device 0000:07:00.1 cannot be used
TELEMETRY: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
hello from core 1
hello from core 2
hello from core 3
hello from core 0


Why is pci_map_resource unable to allocate memory? Evn though, I have set up the huge pages and IOMMU according to the guide?
Why does it say "No free 1048576 kB hugepages reported on node 0" even though I have setup the huge pages?

AnonHugePages:   2586624 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:    1024
HugePages_Free:     1024
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:         4194304 kB

Thanks for help in advance!!

Hello
can you share the result of
sudo lspci | grep Eth 
please to see which interface you have.
thank you

These are the main controllers I would be using :
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Solarflare Communications XtremeScale SFC9250 10/25/40/50/100G Ethernet Controller (rev 01)
07:00.1 Ethernet controller: Solarflare Communications XtremeScale SFC9250 10/25/40/50/100G Ethernet Controller (rev 01)

Hi . ok so in the list https://core.dpdk.org/supported/nics/solarflare/
. so run your app with sudo to check if you met same issues after creating huges pages

As for the hugepage problem, it is better to reboot the host and then, prior to running the application, invoke dpdk-hugepages tool as follows:
sudo ./usertools/dpdk-hugepages.py --setup 2G

or
sudo ./usertools/dpdk-hugepages.py -p 1G --setup 2G

(instead of attempting to configure huge pages manually).
As for the cannot map resource failure, by the looks of it, the application is being run as non-privileged user. One should invoke it with sudo as follows:
sudo ./dpdk-helloworld -l 0-3 -n 4

Also, one should check that the NIC in question is bound to vfio-pci driver (or to uio-pci-generic) in case the NIC does not employ bifurcated driver model.
One may also want to specify exact devices to use by getting an -a option device on the list of EAL arguments (before the -- separator) as follows:
sudo ./dpdk-helloworld -a 0000:07:00.0 -a 0000:07:00.1 -- -l 0-3 -n 4

In case above tips do not prove helpful, the OP should consider adding more information: OS distribution/version, DPDK version, NIC vendor ID and device ID.

Thank you so much for the advice. Unfortunately, I have tried all of your suggestions and none work.
First, I tried to use dpdk-hugepages which causes DPDK to freeze, the console print the following messages.(I can type things in the console but nothing happens)
'''
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 32
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
'''
Second, all cmds are using sudo
Third, yes confirmed with dpdk-devbind -s
OS:Rocky9.4
DPDK:dpdk-stable-23.11.1
NIC:Solarflare X2522

basically you need to run application within sudo command because it requires to read /dev/vfio (only for root).
as said @user23509140 you need to create at first hugepages.
You can run without being root by running before hello application and after binding the pci address to dpdk:
sudo chmod a+w -R /dev/hugepages
sudo chmod a+r+w /dev/vfio
